# Javascript: Syntax error when using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a dynamic bar chart with divs that changes depending upon data loaded from a JSON file.

However, I cannot seem to modify any divs through javascript. The following code results in an error in Chrome:

```
document.getElementById("div123").style.width = 500px;
```

The DIV in question is defined in CSS above the javascript and has id="div123".

What am I doing wrong? How can I change divs dynamically in a lightweight way, without using a library?

Comment: Enclose the string `500px` in quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use quotes

```
document.getElementById("div123").style.width = "500px";
```